# How navigation works in custom loop within shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, query

I am using a shortcode to display a custom query. The shortcode is use in page. Everything is fine, only the navigation that I can't get it working correctly.

Here is the function that I use to display the query calling by the shortcode:

```
$the_query = my_custom_query();
if($the_query){
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';

  endwhile;

  next_posts_link(); previous_posts_link(); //here I can't get it right.

  else : $return_string =  'no result';  

 endif;
 }else{ echo 'ordinary page';}
```

The `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` not showing up. Is it because the shortcode been inside the page main loop?

**Update**
this is the function to get the custom query

```
function my_custom_query(){
         $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
         $args = array(
        'post_type'=>any,
        'posts_per_page'=> 1,
        'max_num_pages'=> 10,
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'meta_query' => array('relation'=>'OR',array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tax1',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'tax1term'
                )),
        'tax_query' => array('relation'=>'OR',array(
                'key' => 'metakey',
                'value' => array(5,30),
                'compare' => 'compare'
                   )) 

    );

       $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args);
        return $custom_query;

}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Now I can get the `next_posts_link(); previous_posts_link();` to display. But the problem is, it linked to a wrong page.  The query results remain same posts on every page (regardless if it is Next or Previous page).

```
$the_query = my_custom_query();
if($the_query){
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
  while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';

  endwhile;

  previous_posts_link('Previous',$the_query->max_num_pages); next_posts_link('Next',$the_query->max_num_pages);  //here I added $the_query->max_num_pages,and they shows up. 
  else : $return_string =  'no result';  

 endif;
 }else{ echo 'ordinary page';}
```

Comment: Concerning the updated query code: Reread Milo's answer & comments below. Again, `$max_num_pages` is the total number of pages, the result of `$found_posts / $posts_per_page`. If you set `posts_per_page` to 1 and the maximum number of pages also to 1 as well --> how do you expect to get more than one post to show?

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo, it should be `10`,now updated.

Answer (score 2):

if you look at `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` [in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/link-template.php), you'll see why they don't work, they use the global `$paged` and `$wp_query` vars to format the links and determine whether or not they appear. you'll have to roll your own pagination using the `paged` and `max_num_pages` vars in your custom query.

Comment: I already added the `paged` in my custom query. The `max_num_pages` somehow is not working. It does not limit the post, so I use `posts_per_page` instead. But the `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` still doesn't works.

Comment: max_num_pages is how next_posts_link determines whether or not there are more pages to display. if you don't pass that value, the link will never show because pages only have a single page. again, look at the functions in source to see how they work.

Comment: yes, i also added `max_num_pages` in the query, but still not working.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of max_num_pages, it is not something you set in a query. add your query code and what you've actually tried to your question or i'm unable to help you further.